# Zero out Ada 2D array of given size

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, ada

I have `M : array (1..3, 1.. 3) of Integer := ((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0));`

I am looking to convert the size of this to be user-determined, i.e., the new array would look something like `M : array (1 .. user_size, 1 .. user_size) of ...`

The problem I'm having is the case of zero-ing out the array. I'm not extremely familiar with Ada, but learning.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: A 2-dimensional aggregate such as `(others => (others => 0))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try

```
(others => (others => 0));
```

Comment: Wow. This is way easier than anything I have tried. Thanks for introducing me to aggregates. I just went and  looked it up in the documentation. Will accept answer once SO allows me to.

Comment: Note you can allocate named elements first then the "others" clause, e.g. (1 => 99, 2 => 101, others => 0) will set the first two elements to a different value.